# NGinx + Wordpress at sub URL converts domain to localhost

Tags: nginx, wordpress

When I go to `http://niklasrosenstein.com/blog` everything is fine, but if I click on a link or go to some page lik `http://niklasrosenstein.com/blog/shop` I end up on `http://localhost/shop`. What am I doing wrong?

Configuration for the Wordpress server that is later used with `proxy_pass`:

```
##
# Internal Wordpress
##
server {
  listen 127.0.0.1:8050;
  root /home/www-data/blog/htdocs;
  index index.php;
  try_files $uri $uri/ /index?$args;

  location / {
    try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php?$args;
  }

  location ~ \.php$ {
    # Pass PHP scripts through FastCGI.
    try_files $uri =404;
    fastcgi_intercept_errors on;
    fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $request_filename;
    fastcgi_index index.php;
    fastcgi_pass php-cgi;
    include /etc/nginx/fastcgi_params;
  }

  location ~* \.(js|css|png|jpg|jpeg|gif|ico)$ {
    # Cache static files as long as possible.
    expires max;
    log_not_found off;
  }

}
```

Public server configuration:

```
server {
  listen 80;
  server_name niklasrosenstein.com;
  client_max_body_size 15M;
  resolver 127.0.0.1;

  ##
  # Locations
  ##
  location = /favicon.ico {
    log_not_found off;
    access_log off;
  }
  location = /robots.txt {
    log_not_found off;
    access_log off;
  }

  ##
  # Wordpress
  ##
  location ~/blog(|(.*))$ {
    access_log /home/www-data/blog/access.log;
    error_log /home/www-data/blog/error.log;
    proxy_pass http://localhost:8050/$2;
  }
}
```

---

@MarkStosberg I was able to make it work for [Gogs](https://gogs.io) by using a regex `location` directive like this. I thought I could make it work the same way with Wordpress. Since there was no local server that would serve Wordpress, I thought I'd just add one with NGinx (therefore two server directives).

```
  ##
  # Gogs Git Server
  ##
  location ~/git(|/(?<giturl>.*))$ {
    access_log /home/gogs/access.log;
    error_log /home/gogs/error.log;
    proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:3000/$giturl;
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

What I see that looks wrong is having two `server` configurations. One is labeled "Internal Wordpress", but it the entire blog is available to the public at `/blog`.   It is unnecessarily complicated to use both a reverse proxy and FastCGI. Simply using `FastCGI` is enough.

I recommend trying a single `server` block with only FastCGI and no reverse proxy and see if that solves your problem.

Some other things to consider:

- Check /etc/hosts to make sure you haven't mapped the domain back to localhost
- Simplify the configuration by removing the 'resolver' directive. Instead, use 12.0.0.1 instead of "localhost" in the configuration.

Comment: Thanks for your reply, I do have a working version running at `http://blog.niklasrosenstein.com`, but I would like to move it to `http://niklasrosenstein,com/blog`. I was able to make it working with [Gogs](https://gogs.io) under `http://blog.niklasrosenstein.com/git`. Please see my updated question, I can't really show the config in a comment. I'll try your two things to consider!

Comment: Removing the resolver directive and using 127.0.0.1 instead didn't fix it, but I end up on `http://127.0.0.1/...` now instead. I wonder why this even is propagated to my browser location when I configured no redirect or the like. There seems to be nothing suspicious in `/etc/hosts` either

Answer (score 0):

I'm not really into the `WordPress` world, but I'll try my best:

Doing `curl -I http://niklasrosenstein.com/blog/shop` gives:

```
HTTP/1.1 301 Moved Permanently
Server: nginx
Date: Tue, 19 Jan 2016 22:41:49 GMT
Content-Type: text/html; charset=UTF-8
Connection: keep-alive
X-Powered-By: PHP/5.4.45-0+deb7u2
Expires: Wed, 11 Jan 1984 05:00:00 GMT
Cache-Control: no-cache, must-revalidate, max-age=0
Pragma: no-cache
Location: http://niklasrosenstein.com/shop/
```

So, no `http://localhost/shop/` for me, but still `301 Moved Permanently`.

- Did you remove the `resolver...` directive?
- Did you check the `hosts` file on your local machine?

Regarding the redirect from `/blog/shop/` to `/shop/`:
 - As the `X-Powered-By: PHP/5.4.45-0+deb7u2` indicates, this is originating at your backend, aka `WordPress`, not at the `nginx` level.
 - I think, you have to configure `WordPress` to make it aware, that it's not served at `http://niklasrosenstein.com/`, but instead at `http://niklasrosenstein.com/blog/`. Have a look at [this](https://codex.wordpress.org/Giving_WordPress_Its_Own_Directory), especially the third point.

Last but not least, as Mark Stosberg already mentioned, your set up seems a bit "weird". As it stands, I can't see any reason why you're using two reverse proxies. Not sure why you're doing it this way; but of course, it's up to you.

Comment: The move to `Location: http://niklasrosenstein.com/shop/` is stange! But maybe you tested it while I was trying another configuration. Checking the hosts file and removing resolver were both things that @MarkStosberg suggested as well. Removing resolver and replying `localhost` with `127.0.0.1` only changed that I end up on `127.0.0.1/shop` instead of `localhost/shop`.

Comment: Regarding the Wordpress site URL, I have already updated it but that doesn't have any effect. :( Maybe I really just need to move Wordpress to a new directory like `blog/htdocs/blog` and use `blog/htdocs` as root.

Comment: I think the way to go is: _You're_ configuring the system in a way it should (re)act and work, not the other way around. (At least this is what I would do being in your position). Maybe [this](http://www.netz39.de/2014/installation-of-wordpress-in-a-subdirectory-with-nginx/) helps as well.